# What 'time of day' did the heavy bombardment period begin?

Tags: moon

In assigning serial definitions to the stratification of lunar regolith with precise ETA of first impact; what year, month, day and time did the heavy bombardment period begin?

Comment: is this a joke?.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Heavy_Bombardment

Comment: Just.. no. Even if dating methods had time-of-day precision over 4 billion years, we would not be able to pinpoint a 'first' crater.

Comment: Thanks. Another perspective on the issue; is there a HBP algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think the [length of a day on Earth](http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2012/11/28/3642932.htm) has been constant since the formation of the Earth?

> The length of an Earth day has been increasing slowly throughout most of the Earth's 4.5-billion-year history, says Dr Rosemary Mardling, mathematical scientist at Monash University, and it all has to do with the Moon.
>
> "The reason is that the Moon is attempting to slow down the spin of
>   the Earth. The Earth was spinning very much faster when the Moon was
>   formed," says Mardling.
>
> Back when the Moon was formed the length of an Earth day was a very
>   brief two to three hours, and a much closer Moon was orbiting the
>   Earth every five hours.
>
> ... the Earth slows down a little bit and the Moon moves away from the
>   Earth," says Mardling.
>
> "... The spin down rate is very slow," says Mardling, "It's about two
>   milliseconds per century. So the Earth's day is getting longer by a
>   500th of a second every century"
>
> ... Since the dinosaurs lived during the Mesozoic era, from 250
>   million years ago to 65 million years ago, day length would have been
>   longer than 21 hours and probably closer to 23 hours.

Given that the length of a day on Earth has never been constant throughout its history it would be totally impossible to assign a year, month day or time of day for the commencement of the heavy bombardment period or any other event in ancient geologic history.